# Is the TV show "Storage Wars" staged?

Tags: television

I've read a few places online where people say that the TV show [Storage Wars](http://www.aetv.com/storage-wars/) is staged and that the producers place items in the lockers.  Does anyone know if that is true?

Comment: Some staging of course takes place, if only to get the best shots on video (lighting, removing items that show brand names not of your sponsors, etc. the normal stuff). That doesn't mean the entire show is staged (though it wouldn't surprise me).

Comment: I suspect that it is more dramatized than staged.  They find things learn the info about then then "discover" them again for the camera and pretend they know all about them at the point of discovery.  I would also suspect that they seed finds from non televised auctions.

Comment: I think the question could be improved by putting a brief description of the show for users that are not in the US (I know, there is a link, but it would be nicer to have a little summary here anyway).

Comment: Storage Wars is currently the subject of a lawsuit - http://www.thewrap.com/tv/article/storage-wars-lawsuit-ae-strikes-back-claims-show-fake-75126